# how to make notification panel based on database in c#

Tags: database

i m making a desktop application in c#  for pharmaceutical company and the stock table contains columns like (**ID,MEDICINE_NAME,PHARMULA,QUANTITY,etc**).And I want to make a notification panel which will contain all the list of all medicines whose quantity is below from the certain level.User will set the level(means user set the level of each medicine )... so please guide me ???

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start writing your query, if it's sql it would be something like "select id,medicine_name,pharmula,quantity from table where quantity <= certain_level" the add it to a datagridview in c# and  if the user wants to manage or change the level of any medicine,use the datagridview events to get the id of the selected row to change the level of the selected medicine with a method and a update query.

Comment: i also want to display popup notification if the medicines is below from certain level and if i click on notification then it should display the medicines below from certain level ....So how could i do that?

Comment: Taking the "popup notification" as another form, you can use a timer in your main form that evaluates a function every "x" time you want to popup if something is below the certain level, you could use the "example query" that I wrote in my first response, that query should be included in the function and you could do something like if the query rows returned >= 0 then popup that medicine(s).